# How to deploy Spring Boot RESTful Web Service Docker img to EC2?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, docker, spring-boot

What I'm trying to do is simple, deploy a Spring Boot RESTful Web Service to EC2 so it's accessible publicly.

For this I need to do the following:

1. Write Spring Boot web service, containerize and test locally - **done**

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

When I docker run this locally on 8080 it works fine (returns static json).

2. Push to Dockerhub - **done**
3. Launch an Amazon Linux AMI on aws and make it http accessible (port 80) - **done**
4. Install apache (httpd) and start - **done**

*Here is where I need some help*

5. I run docker image from dockerhub like so

   ```
   docker run --rm -p 80:8080 kaspartr/demo
   ```

It doesn't allow cause of course the port is taken by apache. And if I stop it and run it is deployed but I cannot access it online.

Can someone please explain how do you deploy docker image into the apache?

Do I need to change the Dockerfile or something else?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Typically I run application on separate port and do docker forward:

Add yo you application.properties

```
server.port=9001
```

And add to docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '1'
services:
  your-service:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '9001:9001'
    environment:
      SERVICE_URL: http://service:9001/path
```

Comment: As I understand: server.port=9001 tells the Spring app to work on port 9001. ports: '9001:9001' directs port 9001 to 9001? Also the your-service should be the same as 'service' in SERVICE_URL? How does apache know to direct all calls to port 80 with path '/courses' to port 9001 or I don't need to use apache at all?

Comment: You are right, those are exposed ports. It depends on your setups but if you have Apache above Tomcat you have to configure it with VirtualHost settings.

Answer (score 1):

Since Apache has already taken port 80, you cannot make your container runs on port 80 too.

My guess is that you are planning to use Apache as a reverse proxy to your container. Try publishing your container to another port, and proxying port 80 to the container using Apache.